# Iteradores std::begin e std::end no contexto de lista circular

Tags: c++, lista, iterator

A classe std::list cria uma lista circular.
Quando crio um iterador para a percorrer deparo-me com uma situação ambígua, que exemplifico:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    list<int> lista;
    lista.push_back(3);
    lista.push_back(6);
    lista.push_back(9);
    list<int>::iterator it;
    it=lista.begin();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout << (*it);
        it++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Neste caso vamos obter o seguinte output:

```
3693369336
```

Ou seja, na última posição se avanço vou parar ao nó "end" que, pelo que entendo é novamente o primeiro da lista.
Existe outra forma de evitar que esta repetição do último/primeiro (uma espécie de nó cabeçalho) de forma a percorrer a lista circularmente sem andar com condições adicionais?

Comment: Onde você leu que `std::list` é circular?

Comment: Posso ter confundido bidirecional com circular agora que pergunta!

Comment: Foi daqui: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/begin/

Comment: Ultrapassar deliberadamente o final da lista causa comportamento indefinido (UB). O *looping* deve ir até `lista.size()` ou `lista.end()` (dependendo do tipo de *looping*)

Comment: Acrescentando ao que já foi dito, os valores que vê são mero acaso da implementação corrente, que do que eu testei, todos os compiladores teem. Ainda assim, não deixa de ser comportamento indefinido como já dito

Comment: @gtpt, um iterador ser bidirecional significa que pode ser incrementado e decrementado.

Comment: Sim já tinha percebido. Foram os tais valores ao acaso que refere o Isac que me baralharam.